# Sort Hashtable with Arrays as values

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting, hashtable, powershell-5.0

**Description**: I'm building a PowerShell-script that searches for files, then gives them unique names, copies them and then verifies them via hash-calculation - I chose to split the script in functions for each step, so it's easier to maintain the whole thing.
To get all values from one function to the other, I chose to use `[hashtable]$FooBar` - inside `$FooBar`, there are multiple arrays, such as `FullName` or `OutputPath` (which may change per file as they will be copied to subfolders named `yyyy-mm-dd`). All arrays are correlating with each other (meaning that index 1 contains all values of the first file, index 2 the values for the second file,...) and this works fine as of now.

A short *simplified* visualisation:

```
$FooBar = @{}
$FooBar.FullName = @()
$FooBar.Size = @()
$FooBar.Ext = @()
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    $FooBar.FullName += $_.FullName
    $FooBar.Size += $_.Length
    $FooBar.Ext += $_.Extension
}
```

However, I now need to sort them all by one value-set of one of the arrays, e.g. the size. Or, visualised again:

```
# From:
$FooBar
Name                           Value
----                           -----
fullname                       {D:\AAA.XYZ, D:\BBB.ZYX, D:\CCC.YZX}
size                           {222, 111, 555}
extension                      {.XYZ, .ZYX, .YZX}

# To:
$FooBar = $FooBar | Sort-Object -Property Size -Descending
$FooBar
Name                           Value
----                           -----
fullname                       {D:\CCC.YZX, D:\AAA.XYZ, D:\BBB.ZYX}
size                           {555, 222, 111}
extension                      {.YZX, .XYZ, .ZYX}
```

I tried `$FooBar.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Size`, but this does not change anything. Google turned up suggestions on how to sort an array of hashtables, but in my case, it's the other way round, and I can't get my head around this because *I don't even understand why this is a problem in the first place*.

**So my question is**: is there any way to sort all arrays inside the hashtable by the value-set of one of the arrays? I can't get my head around this.

*Disclaimer*: I'm a PowerShell-autodidact with no reasonable background in scripting/programming, so it might well be that my "include everything in one hashtable"-solution isn't going to work at all or might be extremely inefficient - if so, please tell me.

Comment: Why not just store all the `FileInfo` objects in a single array?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that the reason comes down to **a)** inexperience and **b)** expected ease-of-use (*see **a)***). I didn't expet such resonance to my question, either. I'm sitting here trying to comprehend/fully understand (and test-wise implement) each and every suggestion so I can select/up-vote them accordingly - as far as I can tell, you all seem to understand my problems better than I do ;-) . This community is simply awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to go about what I believe you are trying to do is `Select-Object`

```
$fooBar = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object FullName, Size, Extension
```

This will create an array of new objects that only have the desired properties.  The reason this works and your method doesn't is because Sort-Object works on properties and the property you are specifying is behind a few layers.

If you need more flexibility than just exact properties, you can create your own like this

```
$fooBar = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object @{Name = 'SizeMB'; Expression = {$_.Size / 1MB}}
```

Or manually create new properties with the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator:

```
$fooBar = Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FullName = $_.FullName
        Extension = $_.Extension
        Size = $_.Size
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you need to add additional properties to the object after it's initially created you have a few options.

## Add-Member

The most common method by far is by using the `Add-Member` cmdlet.

```
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NewProperty -Value 'MyValue'

$object
```

Something important to keep in mind is that by default this cmdlet does not return anything.  So if you place the above statement at the end of a function and do not separately return the object, your function won't return anything. Make sure you either use the `-PassThru` parameter (this is also useful for chaining `Add-Member` commands) or call the variable afterwards (like the example above)

## Select-Object

You can select all previous properties when using calculated properties to add members.  Keep in mind, because of how `Select-Object` works, all methods from the source object will not be carried over.

```
$fooBar | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'NewProperty'; Expression = {'MyValue'}}
```

## psobject.Properties

This one is my personal favorite, but it's restricted to later versions of PowerShell and I haven't actually seen it used by anyone else yet.

```
$fooBar.psobject.Properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new('NewProperty', 'MyValue'))
$fooBar
```

Each member type has it's own constructor.  You can also add methods to `$fooBar.psobject.Methods` or either type to `$fooBar.psobject.Members`. I like this method because it feels more explicit, and something about adding members with members feels right.

## Summary

The method you choose is mostly preference.  I would recommend `Add-Member` if possible because it's the most used, therefore has better readability and more people who can answer questions about it.

I would also like to mention that it's usually best to avoid adding additional members if at all possible. A function's return value should ideally have a reliable form.  If someone is using your function and they have to guess when a property or method will exist on your object it becomes very difficult to debug.  Obviously this isn't a hard and fast rule, but if you need to add a member you should at least consider if it would be better to refactor instead.

Comment: Chosen as answer because it really does explain everything in an easy to understand language. There's only one thing that I don't understand: Can I add further `[PSCustomObject]@{}`s outside this function? Because of the intended modularity of my functions, I'd like to be able to create/add properties to `$fooBar` afterwards. However, I cannot get that to work *properly* (I tried `Add-Member` and repeating your last script with other variables). I'm sorry, as I know that this is most likely out of the scope of my question, but it does seem to me that it would make your answer even better.

Comment: @flolilolilo Definitely in scope of the original question I think :) I added a section on adding properties after the initial creation.  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a small note: `Add-Member` seems to use `-Name`, not `-MemberName`. (*Add-Member : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MemberName'.*) But that's the only critique I can come up with. :-)

Comment: Indeed it is :) I had hastily changed it from `-NotePropertyName` and `-NotePropertyValue` so it was compatible with more versions and forgot to double check!  Thanks for letting me know, it's updated now.

Answer (score 4):

*For all practical purposes I'd strongly suggest you just store the objects you need in a single array, sort that once and then reference the individual properties of each object when needed:*

```
$FooBar = Get-ChildItem |Sort-Object -Property Length

# Need the Extension property of the object at index 4?
$FooBar[4].Extension
```

---

To answer your actual question:

[`Array.Sort()` has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes keys and values arrays separately. You could make a copy of the array you want to sort on for each other property you want to sort:

```
# Create hashtable of correlated arrays 
$FooBar = @{}
$FooBar.FullName = @()
$FooBar.Size = @()
$FooBar.Ext = @()
# Types cast explicitly to avoid Array.Sort() calling .CompareTo() on the boxing object
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    $FooBar.FullName += [string]$_.FullName
    $FooBar.Size     += [int]$_.Length
    $FooBar.Ext      += [string]$_.Extension
}

# Define name of reference array property
$SortKey = 'Size'

# Sort all arrays except for the reference array
$FooBar.Keys |Where-Object {$_ -ne $SortKey} |ForEach-Object {
    # Copy reference values to new array
    $Keys = $FooBar[$SortKey].Clone()

    # Sort values in target array based on reference values
    [array]::Sort($Keys,$FooBar[$_])
}

# Finally sort the reference array
[array]::Sort($FooBar[$SortOn])
```

*The above only works as long as the reference array is made up of value types*

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell makes working with objects ridiculously easy.

Try:

```
$FooBar = Get-Childitem
$FooBar | Get-Member
```

This will tell you that `$Foobar` actually contains objects of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` type, and show you the `Properties` available.

```
$FooBarSortedBySizeDesc  = $FooBar | Sort-Object Length -Descending
$FooBarFullNamesOnly = $FooBar.FullName
```